# Is angular RouterModule singleton throughout the app?

Tags: angular, router

I'm new to Angular and studying Angular tutorial here.
I got so confused with this code related to routing system in Angular:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {path: 'heroes', component: HeroesComponent}
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes)
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

The code is form here: https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt5

I'm wondering how is this working.
I learned that `imports` means this module is gonna use modules in the import statement and the module will export those in `exports` list. So based on this, this class imports `RouterModule` which ran `forRoot` function, and exports another `RouterModule`.

But here, it seems like there's only one `RouterModule` object and `RouterModule` in both `imports` and `exports` list are the same one so that the one in `exports` list is also effected by `forRoot()` function. Is this right?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what your point is, but this `AppRoutingModule` is in simple words: Importing the `RouterModule`, adding `routes` to it and then exporting the `RouterModule` again, which means you'll only need to import `AppRoutingModule` in another module to have access to `RouterModule`

Comment: @MikeS. Thanks for the comment. What I meant was that whether `RouterModule` that we import and export are the same object or not.

Comment: I see :) They are indeed the same, just like when you seclare a component and export it from the same module.

Comment: Got it. Thanks! Is there any chance to see how is this happened? I'm just wondering the inside of Angular.